# Flatness of $\Omega^1_{X/S}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Let $f : X\to Y$ be a syntomic morphism of locally Noetherian $S$-schemes (i.e. flat and lci) and assume $X$ and $Y$ are smooth over a locally Noetherian scheme $S$.

> **Q1:** is $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$ a flat $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module?

The first answer here [Flatness of sheaf of relative Kahler differentials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75410/flatness-of-sheaf-of-relative-kahler-differentials) contains an example of a syntomic morphism with flat $\Omega^1$ as in the question.

If the answer to the question is "no", as I expect,

> **Q2:**is it "yes" under the additional assumption that $S$ is the spectrum of a local Artin ring and the dimension of the fibers of $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$ at the closed points of $Y$ is constant?

**A counterexample to Q1?**

A simple counterexample to Q1 has been described in the comments. However I'm now a bit confused by it, so maybe I'm missing something at the beginning.

The example is the squaring map on $\mathbf{A}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}}$.

However, let's consider the squaring map $f$ on $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}}$ and the question is: is $\Omega^1_f$ flat over the base $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}}$?

$\Omega^1_f$ is finitely presented over the source $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}}$, which is in turn finite over the target $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}}$ via $f$, so $\Omega^1_f$, renamed as $\mathcal{F}$, is a finitely presented module over the base $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}}$. The locus of points of $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}}$ at which $\mathcal{F}$ is flat is open, so by properness of $\mathbf{P}^1$, in order to check flatness of $\mathcal{F}$, it is enough to check it on the special fiber.

Is $\Omega^1_{f_0}$, the module of differentials of the squaring map $f_0$ on $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{F}_2}$, flat as a module on the base copy of $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{F}_2}$? The answer is yes, as can be checked locally on basic affines (this is essentially done in the comments).

But then $\mathcal{F}$ is flat on the base $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}}$, and so is its restriction to $\mathbf{A}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}} = \mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}}-\{\infty\}$. Since formation of $\Omega^1$ is local on the base, this is the $\Omega^1$ discussed in the comments.

The question is, where is the mistake located? Somewhere in the comments, or in this argument? I think I'd be already fully satisfied by an answer to this question. Thanks!

(I guess all this shows is that $f_*\Omega^1_f$ is flat over the base $\mathbf{P}^1$, which is consistent with the comments too. I'll leave this here anyway, in case further comments are warranted)

Comment: Did you check any examples of non-smooth morphisms? For example, the squaring map on $\mathbf{A}^1_S$ with $S=\operatorname{Spec}(k)$?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger In that case for $A = k[x]$, $B = k[t,x]/(t^2-x)$, we have $\Omega^1_{B/A} = (k[t,x]dt)/(2tdt)$. If $k$ has char $2$ this is $k[t,x]dt$, so flat over $k[x]$. If $k$ has char not $2$, then this is $k[t,x]dt/(tdt)=k[x]dt$, flat over $k[x]$. Maybe I'm missing something? I agree we shouldn't expect the question to have a positive answer (at least the first), but I'd like to see why

Comment: Doesn't your example work as a counterexample when you take $k=\mathbb{Z}$? Or does that violate some condition I'm missing?

Comment: @AchimKrause Yes, you're right it does.

Comment: It is not a counterexample to the second question, though, because the assumption on the fibral dimension isn't met. The example shows the fiber at the closed point $(2, x)$ of $\mathbf{A}^1_{\mathbf{Z}}$ of $\Omega^1_{f}$, with $f : \mathbf{A}^1_{\mathbf{Z}}\to\mathbf{A}^1_{\mathbf{Z}}$ the map $\mathbf{Z}[x]\to\mathbf{Z}[t,x]/(t^2-x)$ sending $x$ to $x$, is a $1$-dimensional $\mathbf{F}_2$-vector space, but at $(3,x)$ it is an infinite dimensional $\mathbf{F}_3$-vector space.

Comment: @AchimKrause Actually I'm now a bit confused by this. See the edit just made

Comment: Your criterion for checking flatness at the special fiber seems not to work as stated. For example, wouldn't it also show that $\mathcal{O}/2$ is flat on $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}}$? (or, even easier: wouldn't it apply to $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_{(2)})$ and show that $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is a flat $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$-module?)

Comment: I think you can fix it by taking the derived basechange instead. This corresponds to asking that you're flat on $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_2}$ and that $2$ acts injectively on the original module. (There's probably a more algebro-geometric way of saying this.) That latter part fails in your case.

Comment: @AchimKrause My proposed (and wrong) criterion was: let $X\to \text{Spec}(A)$, for $A$ a dvr with max'l ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, be a proper scheme of finite type, $M$ a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Then $M$ is $X$-flat if its special fiber $M_0$ is $X_0$-flat. This is not true as you point out. You're suggesting to fix it by further assuming that $\text{Tor}_1^{\mathcal{O}_X}(M, \mathcal{O}_{X_0}) = 0$, or $\text{Tor}_1^A(M, A/\mathfrak{m})=0$. I agree this should do.

Comment: My error was in assuming that if the **fiber** of a coherent module $M$, $M_0$, is flat, then $M$ is flat at the points contained in $X_0$, which is of course wrong as your example shows: $X = \text{Spec}(\mathbf{Z}_{(2)})$ with $M = \mathbf{F}_2^{\sim}$. While $M_0$ is flat over $X_0$, of course $M$ is not flat at the closed point of $X$. This deduction step (flatness of fiber implies flatness at the points in the fiber) can I guess be made to work under the $\text{Tor}_1$ assumption I added.

Comment: I think using Noetherianity to argue that the completion map $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\wedge}$ is faithfully flat, and using that these assumptions do imply flatness of $M_x^{\wedge} = M_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\wedge}$.

Comment: Bottom line, here should be the correct criterion.
Let $f : X\to \text{Spec}(A)$ be a proper morphism of finite type with $A$ a dvr with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and $M$ a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module.
(1) If $\text{Tor}_1^A(M, A/\mathfrak{m})=0$, then $M$ is $A$-flat iff $M_0$ is $A_0$-flat (notation as before).
(2) If $\text{Tor}_1^{\mathcal{O}_X}(M, \mathcal{O}_{X_0})=0$, then $M$ is $X$-flat iff $M_0$ is $X_0$-flat.

Comment: I guess the last thing I'm wondering about is whether one can replace the $\text{Tor}_1$ assumptions with an assumption on the support of $M$ instead, such as $\text{Supp}(M) = X$.

Comment: Your guess about support might be incorrect: you can always take a direct sum with a free module to make the support "full".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the calculation in the comment is incorrect. Let $S=\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ for a field $k$, let $m\geq 2$ be an integer invertible in $k$, and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be the $m$-th power map on $\mathbf{A}^1_k$, i.e. $\operatorname{Spec} k[x] \to \operatorname{Spec} k[y]$ with $f^*(y) = x^m$. Then $\Omega^1_{k[x]/k[y]} = k[x]dx/k[x]dy = k[x]dx/(k[x]mx^{m-1}dx)\simeq k[x]/(x^{m-1})$. As a $k[y]$-module, this is torsion: we have $y\cdot \Omega^1_{k[x]/k[y]}=0$. So it is not flat over $k[y]$. This gives a counterexample to both questions.